# What can be some bachelor thesis ideas in Quantum random walks?

Tags: quantum-computing, project-topic, quantum-walk

**Note:** *Cross-posted on [Quantum Computing Stack Exchange](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5918/what-can-be-some-bachelor-thesis-ideas-in-quantum-random-walks).*

---

I am an undergraduate, reading about quantum information and quantum technology. For about some time, I have been interested in the applications of quantum walks to quantum algorithms. What can be some bachelor thesis ideas in quantum random walks? Can anybody suggest a starting point?

Comment: Cross-posted on [quantumcomputing.SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/5918/55)

Comment: [Asking for a research topic is not a suitable question for this site](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/802/policy-questions-about-topic-for-research-project). It's too broad. The best person to ask is a professor in your department.